# Android: make AudioRecord onPeriodicNotification be called in another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, record, audiorecord

So, i am using ExtAudioRecorder: http://i-liger.com/sites/default/files/ExtAudioRecorder.java
My problem is that onPeriodNotification is called on the UI thread. What would be an ellegant sollution to this. Making new thread in every onPeriodNotification call seems very  excessive. I tried initializing the recorder in new Thread(), but calls were still made on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  But what you can do is post a message to the second thread in the onPeriodNotification, and then return.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using HandlerThread and posting to it in onPeriodNotification.

Comment: It's ages later, but could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: @C-Bk You can't force this function onto another thread.  You can start a thread, add a looper to it, and post a message to that looper that tells it to do something (or even has a runnable to run in it).  That will get you the effect you want, with just a switching delay.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm having the same problem, with ExtAudioRecorder. onPeriodNotification brings up an error:
````write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)````
From what I've read, it might be a thread problem. I just don't know how to implement what you've just explained. ( I have the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074934/extaudiorecorder-write-failed-ebadf-bad-file-descriptor-in-recording-audi)